# How to write dynamically allocated 2D 'array' in a file?

Tags: c++, arrays, file

So for a school assignment I was writing a program that uses dynamic 2D 'arrays' to model matrices and perform operations on them. So what I did was create a  structure called *matrix* which contains two integers for the rows and columns, and a double pointer for the 'array'. I initialized the pointers like this:

```
int **ary=new int*[row];
for(int i=0;i<row;++i)
     ary[i]=new int[col];
```

Now I know that my program is going to look horribly slow and inefficient and generally horrible to people on this site, but just keep in mind that I am doing a *school assignment* and I can't use *fancy* things like vectors and all.

Then I tried to write and then read the structure objects in a binary file like using an fstream object *y* like this:

```
matrix M;
y.write((char*)&M,sizeof M);
y.read((char*)&M,sizeof M);
```

The program worked, but what I entered was different from what the file read. Why is that so? And what are other methods (that use fstream) to store my matrices in a file?

**NOTE:** As is evident, I am completely new to this site, and as of yet I do not know the proper, um, etiquette of asking questions on this site. If my question seems weird in some way or is missing some information, please leave a comment. Constructive edits are welcome.

Comment: What is `M`? Please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hint: saving pointers to file doesn't make sense. You should write each **values** instead of pointers.

Comment: C++ *is not Java*. Stop `new`ing everything you create. We have `std::vector`, `std::array`, and language-level arrays. You don't have to `new` every object you use.

Comment: There is no 2D array.

Comment: @NicolBolas I already mentioned in the question that I am, alas, bound to do what my school curriculum says, and I hate myself for that.

Comment: @Olaf that's why I said 'arrays' and not arrays.

Comment: So why not use a 2D _array_?

Comment: you probably want to read up on [serialization](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization).

Comment: @MikeCAT I have to save multiple matrices to the same file. Writing won't be a problem but to read the matrices back, I will want to know the size of the matrix.

Comment: @G-man Save the size of the matrix before saving each elements.

Comment: `Then I tried to write and then read the structure objects in a binary file`  What is this obsession with new programmers writing to *binary* files?  I've seen so many posts from beginners who do not know what they're writing to such a file, and write things like pointer values.  Just write the number of rows, number of columns, and then the data to a file.

Comment: @G-man If you want to know why your routine could never have worked, the value of `sizeof M` in your `read` and `write` calls are *compile-time* value.  Let's say that `sizeof M` is 50 bytes.  That 50 doesn't change value, no matter what the dimensions of your matrix are.  It could be `1 x 1` or `10000 x 10000`.  Given that information, even if you didn't know the ins and outs of pointers, you see that there is no way saving in the way you've done could have worked.

Comment: *but just keep in mind that I am doing a school assignment and I can't use fancy things like vectors and all.* -- Many school assignments posted here *do* use `std::vector`, and it is debatable if a vector is "fancy".

Answer (score 2):

You can do that if you allocate all the memory in one single block (See the other answer(s) if you don't want to do that):

```
int* block = new int[row*col]
for (int i=0; i < row; i++)
   ary[i] = block + i*col;
```

Basically I'm allocating a single large array then make each row point to the corresponding portion of the array.
Now if you write

```
y.write(static_cast<char*>(block), sizeof(int) * row * col);
y.read(static_cast<char*>(block), sizeof(int) * row * col);
```

you will get the same thing out. It's probably now obvious that if you don't know the values of `row` and `col` when you read this won't work. You will need to write them to the file as well and read the first when reading.

Answer (score 1):

Every pointer at `ary` is a different block at memory, so you need to write and read them separately:

Write:

```
for(int i=0;i<row;++i) 
   y.write((char*)&(M[i]),sizeof(int) * col);
```

Read:

```
for(int i=0;i<row;++i) 
   y.read((char*)&(M[i]),sizeof(int) * col);
```

If you post the definition of `matrix` I could help better.

Comment: Don't use C-style casts, use `static_cast` instead